# java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, oracle10g, c3p0

I am using the JPA(hibernate) for the ORM and c3po for connection pooling. While I am able to do all the CRUD operations it gives me the below error while accessing the the data:

Here are the tools:
Hibernate 3.2.1, 
Oracle 10g, 
ojdbc14, 
connection pool: c3p0-0.9.

And the stack trace:

```java
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException(DBError.java:689)
        at oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:4180)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys(NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:3578)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:730)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:121)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:51)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
        at com.bbn.dbservices.test.BillabilityPeriodsTest.getBillPeriods(BillabilityPeriodsTest.java:33)
        at com.bbn.dbservices.controller.ServiceController.generateReportsTest(ServiceController.java:355)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:654)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:378)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:366)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:781)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:726)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:636)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:545)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException(DBError.java:689)
        at oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:4180)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys(NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:3578)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:730)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:121)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:51)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
        at com.bbn.dbservices.test.BillabilityPeriodsTest.getBillPeriods(BillabilityPeriodsTest.java:33)
        at com.bbn.dbservices.controller.ServiceController.generateReportsTest(ServiceController.java:355)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:654)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:378)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:366)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:781)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:726)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:636)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:545)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the latest JDBC drivers, I think you need at least the  10.2.0.1 drivers and the db also need to be 10.2+

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc101040.html

Answer (score 1):

Your database may not support retrieving auto-generated keys:

> **Oracle  10.1.0 supports:**
>
> Full support for JDBC 3.0 except for:
>   retrieving auto-generated keys
>   result-set holdability
>   returning multiple result-sets.
>
> **Oracle  10.2.0 supports:**
>
> Full support for JDBC 3.0
>   Note that there is no real change in the support
>   for the following in the database. All
>   that has changed is that some methods
>   that previously threw SQLException now
>   do something more reasonable instead.
>   result-set holdability
>   returning multiple result-sets.

In that case, try to set `hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys` to `false` to disable the *use of JDBC3 `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()` to retrieve natively generated keys after insert.*

Comment: Thanks Pascal. It solved the problem. The other solution I found was to use ojbbc6 (since am on java6) and it dint give me any errors and is compatible with 10.2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

this is the crux of your problem `oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:4180)` try changing or not using that annotation related to getting generated keys.